# Laravel update database with concate string is not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, concatenation

Now I am trying to update Laravel Eloquent Model like this:

```
                Res_Reservations::where('time_id', $time['id'])
                    ->where('date',  $bus['date'])
                    ->where('valid',  config('config.TYPE_SCHEDULE_UNREMOVED'))
                    ->update(['time_id' => $time['move'], 'reason' => 'reason' . $notesAdd]);
```

I want to add extra string to the 'reason' field as below.

> reason field = reason field + $notesAdd;

But it does not working. It acts as below.

> reason field = 'reason' + $notesAdd;

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without making an extra query by using a [raw expression](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions).

```
Res_Reservations::where('time_id', $time['id'])
                ->where('date',  $bus['date'])
                ->where('valid',  config('config.TYPE_SCHEDULE_UNREMOVED'))
                ->update([
                    'time_id' => $time['move'],
                    'reason' => DB::raw("CONCAT(reason, '" . $notesAdd . "')")
                ]);
```

Comment: I like this one better. Wish I thought of it.

Comment: @treeface, Thanks much for your response. And I have one more problem. when the reason field is null, then it's CONCAT is not working. Please help more!

Comment: @Alex You can use a mysql control flow function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html . So something like `IF(reason IS NULL, NULL, CONCAT(reason, 'whatever'))`

Comment: @treeface Thanks. Can you explain more detailed? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379150/laravel-eloquent-model-update-according-to-condition-of-field-value-null-or-exis. Now I have posted question more detailed about this. Please answer in this question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will need you to load the record first so that it becomes an Laravel object, then update the property, and save the record.

```
$record = Res_Reservations::where('time_id', $time['id'])
                ->where('date',  $bus['date'])
                ->where('valid',  config('config.TYPE_SCHEDULE_UNREMOVED'))->first();

$record->update(['time_id' => $time['move'], 'reason' => $record->reason . $notesAdd]);
```