# Laravel Eloquent model update according to condition of field value null or existing

Tags: php, laravel, conditional-statements, concatenation

I am trying to update Laravel Eloquent model like this.

```
Res_Reservations::where('time_id', $time['id'])
                ->where('date',  $bus['date'])
                ->where('valid',  config('config.TYPE_SCHEDULE_UNREMOVED'))
                ->where(function($query) use($time, $notesAdd) {
                    $query->whereNull('reason', function($query) use ($time, $notesAdd) {
                        return $query->update([
                            'time_id' => $time['move'],
                            'reason' => $notesAdd
                        ]);
                    })
                    ->orWhere('reason', '=', '', function($query) use ($time, $notesAdd) {
                        return $query->update([
                            'time_id' => $time['move'],
                            'reason' => $notesAdd
                        ]);
                    })
                    ->orWhere('reason', '<>', '', function($query) use ($time, $notesAdd) {
                        return $query->update([
                            'time_id' => $time['move'],
                            'reason' => DB::raw("CONCAT(reason, \r\n'" . $notesAdd . "')")
                        ]);
                    });
                });
```

But it does not working.

In other words, I want to update as below.

- if 'reason' is null or emptystring

  ```
  Res_Reservations::where('time_id', $time['id'])
                  ->where('date',  $bus['date'])
                  ->where('valid',  config('config.TYPE_SCHEDULE_UNREMOVED'))
                  ->update([
                      'time_id' => $time['move'],
                      'reason' => $notesAdd
                  ]);
  ```
- else

  ```
  Res_Reservations::where('time_id', $time['id'])
                  ->where('date',  $bus['date'])
                  ->where('valid',  config('config.TYPE_SCHEDULE_UNREMOVED'))
                  ->update([
                      'time_id' => $time['move'],
                      'reason' => DB::raw("CONCAT(reason, '\r\n" . $notesAdd . "')")
                  ]);
  ```

  What is my mistake? And how can I make statements simpler? Please let me know~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is wrong to use `update` function inside the callback of `where` function

You have to do it in 2 queries like:

```
Res_Reservations::where('time_id', $time['id'])
    ->where('date', $bus['date'])
    ->where('valid', config('config.TYPE_SCHEDULE_UNREMOVED'))
    ->where(function ($query
    {
        $query->where('reason', null)
            ->orWhere('reason', '');
    })
    ->update([
        'time_id' => $time['move'],
        'reason'  => $notesAdd,
    ]);


Res_Reservations::where('time_id', $time['id'])
    ->where('date', $bus['date'])
    ->where('valid', config('config.TYPE_SCHEDULE_UNREMOVED'))
    ->where('reason', '!=',  null)
    ->where('reason', '!=' '');
    ->update([
        'time_id' => $time['move'],
        'reason'  => DB::raw('CONCAT(reason, "\r\n' . $notesAdd . '")'),
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks! And is it possible to merge 2 queries as one?

Comment: No you cannot, but you can play around, and assign the common condition to a variable then clone it for each query and add the custom condition for each query

Comment: Thanks @Aboudeh87