# Laravel Update: add new value to existing value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I wanted to update the query data with existing value without looping, is there any other way can make it.

example

```
Product Table
id  name     version  color
1   iphone    4       white,black
2   iphone    5       white,black
```

Update method

```
Product::where('name', "iphone")->update(['color' => existing.color+ , red]);

Result
id  name     version  color
1   iphone    4       white,black,red
2   iphone    5       white,black,red
```

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379150/laravel-eloquent-model-update-according-to-condition-of-field-value-null-or-exis

Answer (score 4):

You can use DB::raw().

```
Product::where('name', "iphone")->update(['color' => DB::raw('CONCAT(color,", red")')]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be accomplished via `DB::update(..)`, e.g:

```
DB::update('UPDATE `products` SET `color`=CONCAT(color,", red") WHERE `name`=?', ['iphone']);
```

more information [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#running-queries).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm maybe something like this:

```
$product = Product::where('name', "iphone")->first();

$product->color .= $newColor;

$product->save();
```

Comment: Should use `.=` for concatenation; `$product->color` would be a string. Also, check the comma; one method would have it, the other wouldn't.